# How to use the provider of other module in android studio under the same project

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-contentprovider

I've used a module as a lib to do the download things(Download Manager). The DownloadManager module uses a provider of itself.

But when I use the DownloadManager to download, it causes IllegalArgumentException says that Unknown URL content://com.package.downloader/Provider

How should I declare the provider, in my main module's Manifest or the downloader module's?

Comment: Does the download manager uses any provider?? Is it custom lib or Android default download manager?

Comment: the download manager uses a provider of itself. It's a custom lib.